# How to convert Quarter years to other format

Tags: vba, excel

I have cells that can either contain time in this format:

`1625` (16 for 2016 and 25 for week 25)
Or in this format

`2016-Q2` (Q2 means quarter 2 if the year)

When converting I want quarters to be the mid week of the quarter

2016-Q1 = 1608

2016-Q2 = 1620

2016-Q3 = 1633

2016-Q4 = 1646

I dont want to convert the times in the cell its in. I want to convert it to YYWW format for a formula for a timeline in another sheet. So I use help cells with the converted value and reference those instead of the values in the other sheet.

I have done this with nested if functions resulting in mile long formulas because the timeline needs to be very long and the time can very well be 2025-Q3.

a `=IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2016-Q1";1608;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2016-Q2";1620;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2016-Q3";1633;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2016-Q4";1646;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2017-Q1";1708;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2017-Q2";1720;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2017-Q3";1733;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2017-Q4";1746;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2018-Q1";1808;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2018-Q2";1820;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2018-Q3";1833;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2018-Q4";1846;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2019-Q1";1908;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2019-Q2";1920;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2019-Q3";1933;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2019-Q4";1946;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2020-Q1";2008;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2020-Q2";2020;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2020-Q3";2033;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2020-Q4";2046;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2021-Q1";2108;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2021-Q2";2120;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2021-Q3";2133;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2021-Q4";2146;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2022-Q1";2208;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2022-Q2";2220;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2022-Q3";2233;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2022-Q4";2246;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2023-Q1";2308;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2023-Q2";2320;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2023-Q3";2333;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2023-Q4";2346;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2024-Q1";2408;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2024-Q2";2420;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2024-Q3";2433;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2024-Q4";2446;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2025-Q1";2508;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2025-Q2";2520;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2025-Q3";2533;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2025-Q4";2546;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2026-Q1";2608;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2026-Q2";2620;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2026-Q3";2633;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2026-Q4";2646;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2027-Q1";2708;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2027-Q2";2720;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2027-Q3";2733;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2027-Q4";2746;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2028-Q1";2808;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2028-Q2";2820;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2028-Q3";2833;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2028-Q4";2846;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2029-Q1";2908;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2029-Q2";2920;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2029-Q3";2933;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2029-Q4";2946;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2030-Q1";3008;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2030-Q2";3020;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2030-Q3";3033;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2030-Q4";3046;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2031-Q1";3108;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2031-Q2";3120;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2031-Q3";3146;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2031-Q4";3146;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2032-Q1";3208;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2032-Q2";3220;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2032-Q3";3233;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2032-Q4";3246;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2033-Q1";3308;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2033-Q2";3320;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2033-Q3";3333;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2033-Q4";3346;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2034-Q1";3408;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2034-Q2";3420;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2034-Q3";3433;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2034-Q4";3446;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2035-Q1";3508;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2035-Q2";3520;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2035-Q3";3533;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2035-Q4";3546;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2036-Q1";3608;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2036-Q2";3620;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2036-Q3";3633;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2036-Q4";3646;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2037-Q1";3708;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2037-Q2";3720;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2037-Q3";3733;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2037-Q4";3746;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2038-Q1";3808;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2038-Q2";3820;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2038-Q3";3833;IF('Gulpilspuls NT'!U4="2038-Q4";3846;'Gulpilspuls NT'!U4))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))`

As you can clearly see this method is not the best. I cant make it this long because nested if functions can only contain 64 levels of nesting. Do you guys have a better suggestion for this?

The formula has to work with both formats of time entry and I need it to be able to convert all the cells 1:1 meaning 1 cell in the calendar has to be 1 converted cell in the other spot that I can use for the formula. If the cell in the calendar does not have YYYY-Q1234? it should just show what it is instead as you can see at the end of my formula.

Comment: I think Mine should work for you... maybe a slightly easier way to do it without the if's, but I think it will work nicely in a way you can understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: I just realized that if the original is in the format of YYWW, that you do **NOT** want it changed to the mid quarter week number.  So we simplify the formulas:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(-A1),A1,MID(A1,3,2) & CHOOSE(RIGHT(A1,1),"08",20,33,46))
```

and if you want YYWW to always be rendered as numeric:

```
=1*IF(ISNUMBER(-A1),A1,MID(A1,3,2) & CHOOSE(RIGHT(A1,1),"08",20,33,46))
```

And here are the results for various samples:

[image]

**EDIT:** If you need to check for blanks, you can do this simply:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=0,"",1*IF(ISNUMBER(-A1),A1,MID(A1,3,2) & CHOOSE(RIGHT(A1,1),"08",20,33,46)))
```

However, if a `0` will not result in a downstream problem, you can use the original, shorter formula, and merely use a custom format to suppress zero returns:  `0;;`

And if you need to check for other conditions for which you don't want to process, you can perform similar actions.

Comment: This worked just one question. If the cell that it is trying to convert is empty it returns 0. Can I change it to return "" i.e blank?

Comment: @FelixTorssell  I will modify the formula to take care of the "blank cell" issue.  It is a simple modification.  But remember to always present all of the circumstances relevant to your particular problem, when presenting a problem.

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry I didnt realize that returning 0 would be an issue before I tested it with my other formula. I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your formula.

```
=IF(AND(LEN(C6)=4,ISERROR(FIND("-",C6))),C6,MID(C6,3,2)&INDEX({"08",20,33,46},RIGHT(C6,1)))
```

Make sure there is no excess space in your data. Not like this "2016-Q1 ", but like this "2016-Q1".

[image]

Comment: And I just change C5 to wherever the data for time might be? will this work if the cell already has data in 1630 way?

Comment: No it wont work if cell has data like 1630. Let me change it a bit.

Comment: ok so some cells have in this format ex 1715 1635 1652 and some cells are like this 2016-q3 2020-q3 if we dont know  the specific weeks. I don't want any of the values in my calander to change. I have recreated the layout of the calendar in another location where I store the new converted times. I then use the converted cells to this format(1730 1752 1925 2518 3306 1605) for referencing in another formula for a timeline of the calendar. The timeline formula only works with values in YYWW format which is why I am doing all of this.

Comment: Could you please visualize with a table where code does not work and what problems does it have ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try again

```
="20"&LEFT(N5,2)&IF(MOD(N5,100)<=8,"-Q1",IF(MOD(N5,100)<=20,"-Q2",IF(MOD(N5,100)<=33,"-Q3",if(MOD(N5,100)<=46,"-Q4","-Q1"))))
```

Should work for everything past year 2000 ;)

Comment: Ok sooo this does the opposite of what I want. I want YYYY-Q1-4 to become YYWW not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do it, however, mid way through Q1, is week 6, so you'll need to adjust if your year doesn't start at 1/1

```
Function get_week(strInput As String) As String

Dim strQ As String
Dim bytQ As Byte
Dim dblMultiplier As Double
Dim intWeekNumber As Integer

strQ = Split(strInput, "-")(0)
bytQ = CByte(Right(strQ, 1))

dblMultiplier = (bytQ - 1) / 4
intWeekNumber = (dblMultiplier * 52)
intWeekNumber = intWeekNumber + (13 / 2)

get_week = Split(strInput, "-")(1) & "-" & CStr(intWeekNumber)

End Function
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with vb., where will this output and how do I choose where it should output?

Comment: in b1, =get_week(a1)